# How to make a completely independent copy of a Python pandas object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, deep-copy

I am trying to make a completely independent copy of a Python pandas object and it feels like I am either missing some key Python understanding about Python objects or not finding the right copy tool. Here is an example (extended from [pandas.DataFrame.copy docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)):

```py
import copy
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
deep = s.copy(deep=True)
deeper = copy.deepcopy(s)
print(s); print(deep); print(deeper)
# 0    [1, 2]
# 1    [3, 4]
# dtype: object
# 0    [1, 2]
# 1    [3, 4]
# dtype: object
# 0    [1, 2]
# 1    [3, 4]
# dtype: object

s[0][0] = 10
print(s); print(deep); print(deeper)
# 0    [10, 2]
# 1     [3, 4]
# dtype: object
# 0    [10, 2]
# 1     [3, 4]
# dtype: object
# 0    [10, 2]
# 1     [3, 4]
# dtype: object
```

As you can see, `deeper` - which I believe follows the Pandas docs advice and what I expected to remain unaltered - still changes.

- What am I missing here? Is this experiment working as expected?
- To achieve my goal of a completely independent copy, do I have to do something scary like writing separate code to iterate/recurse my original Pandas object and deepcopy each "layer"?

Comment: It's working as expected as I don't think Pandas implement [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) method. `pickle.dumps` it to something and `pickle.loads`, or maybe `pd.Series(copy.deepcopy(s.to_dict)))`.

Comment: The fundamental thing here is that you are using an `object` dtype series,

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang, those are good ideas. `pickle` may be a bit heavy-handed, but should definitely work for some situations and also is explicit. I'll have to experiment with `pd.Series(copy.deepcopy(s.to_dict)))` more.

Comment: Why are you using a pandas series of Python lists?

Comment: Mainly just following the pandas docs example. But also, why not? Are you getting at that the pd.Series shouldn't be used in a case like this?

Comment: No, making a `pd.Series` of `object` dtype that contains `list` objects is not a good use-case for pandas. Where in the docs did you see this?

Comment: As for why not, well, it sort of defeats the purpose of pandas/numpy. Unless you really need the index alignment features, a pandas series of pythons lists is basically a less performant Python list of lists

Comment: "Where in the docs": it's the last paragraph on the docs page link in the original question (no way I can find to hyperlink the exact location, sorry). Starts with "Note that when copying an object".

Comment: Something strange happened and a good answer to this question was removed (maybe it was a ChatGPT generated one and that's not allowed on SO?). The practical essence of that post was to use something like `d = copy.deepcopy(s)  ;  d.values[:] = [copy.deepcopy(x) for x in d.values]`, and in my testing that seemed to stabilize this toy experiment problem.